# Access base class object from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I may be understanding inheritance wrong but say if:

I have base class called Base and a derived class of Base called Derived,

In a function of the Derived class, can I access the Base object of the Derived class?
I guess a bit like *this but of object type Base ?

EDIT: I am overriding a function Base::foo() in the Derived class, but in this overridden function Derived::foo() i want to call the original function with the Base object.

Derived::foo() const {

```c++
double Derived::foo() const {
  // s is a variable only associated with Derived
  double x;
  x = s + Base.foo(); // this is the line i dont know what im doing?!
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Like https://ideone.com/WCP5SS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call a base class function that you are overriding you call `Base::Fun(...)`.

You do the following `Base::foo()`, here is a full code sample:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual double  foo() const
    {
        return 5;
    };
};

class Derived : Base
{
    int s;

public:

    Derived() : s(5)
    {
    }

    virtual double  foo() const
    {
        // s is a variable only associated with Derived
        double x;

        //NOTE THE Base::foo() call
        x = s + Base::foo(); // this is the line i dont know what im doing?!
        return x;
    }
};
```

Comment: Also, a quick addition if you ever want to override a function make sure to mark the function as virtual.

Comment: Thanks, was being a tad dim!

Answer (score 10):

A `Derived*` is implicitly convertible to `Base*`, so you can just do:

```
const Base *base = this;
```

Although you don't usually need this because any member of `Base` is inherited by `Derived`.

But if `foo()` is virtual, then doing this:

```
const Base *base = this;
base->foo();
```

or equivalently:

```
static_cast<const Base*>(this)->foo();
```

will not call `Base::foo()` but `Derived::foo()`. That's what virtual functions do. If you want to call a specific version of a virtual function you just specify which one:

```
this->Base::foo(); // non-virtual call to a virtual function
```

Naturally, the `this->` part is not really necessary:

```
Base::foo();
```

will work just fine, but some people prefer to add the `this->` because the latter looks like a call to a static function (I have no preference on this matter).